# can't direct manual login away from sessions#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

Running Ruby 1.9.3p545 rails 4.1.4
I have an application where users canlogin through facebook, twitter, etc and can rehister manually. I would like a logon process for those who have registered manually.
Routes are
         get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'

```
     get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')

     get 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'

     get "sign_up" => "profiles#new", :as => "sign_up"

     get "log_in" => "logins#new"

     post "log_in" => "logins#login"
```

Everything works fine except the manual logi. logins.new presents a form ok bu the subsequent submit always ends up in sessions controller at create.
I defined a login controller and tried to use the above post in the routes to get it away from the omniauth process in sessions#create.
The login form is

## Log in

```
    <%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
   <p>
    <%= label_tag :email %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
   </p>
   <p>
   <%= label_tag :password %><br />
   <%= password_field_tag :password %>
  </p>
  <p class="button">
  <%= submit_tag "Sign in" %>
  </p>
  <% end %>
```

logins#login is

```
 def login

    authorized_user = Profile.authenticate(params[:name_or_email],params[:password])

   if authorized_user

     flash[:notice] = "Wow Welcome again, you logged in as #{authorized_user.username}"

     redirect_to(:action => 'home')

   else

     flash[:notice] = "Invalid Username or Password"

     flash[:color]= "invalid"

    render "login"  

   end
```

Is tehre any way I can direct the submit of the login form away from the sessions controller?
Thanks in advance
    end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
```

is what's throwing things off.  It makes the form post to `sessions_path`.  Try replacing it with `<%= form_tag log_in_path do %>`, or, better, yet, replace it with `<%= form_tag "" do %>` since the default is to post to the same URL as the current page.

Some more clarification:

```
<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
```

generates the following HTML (roughly, skipping some details that aren't relevant to this issue):

```
<form action="/sessions" method="post">
```

since `/sessions` is the path to `sessions#create`.  You want the `action` to be `/log_in`, i.e. the path to `logins#login`, so you want to change the argument you're passing to `form_tag`.

Since you're already on the page `log_in`, if you leave the action blank, i.e.:

```
<form method="post">
```

it will get you where you want, since the default behavior of the browser is to post to the same page.

Comment: I'm ashamed to admit I missed that. Cut and pasting has its pitfalls. Thanks.